# How to maintain header image size in media screen query?

Tags: html, css, header, screen, media

How can I keep my header image's size constant when it goes from the original resolution to the media screen queries ... using only CSS and/or HTML if possible?

From index.html:

```
<header>
        <iframe src="header.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="240"></iframe>
    </header>
```

From header.html:

```
<header>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <a href="index.html" target="_parent"><img src="images/$RK6ZV6D.JPG" alt="logo" width="60%"></a></div>
```

From main.css:

```
header {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: -2%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px){
header { 
    margin-bottom: -2%;
}
header img {
    width: 100%;
}
header iframe {
    height: 200px;
    margin: -0.5% -0.5% -0.9% -0.5%;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 840px){
header {
    margin: auto;
}
header iframe {
    height: 165px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
img {
    border: 0.5px 0.5px solid #000;
    width: 90%;
}
}
```

Thanks for further help and info!

Comment: can you show your code so we can help you

Comment: Ah, yes! Will update with such! Thank you!

Comment: what size is the image/ what size do you want it to be..

Comment: 60% to its 558 × 360 px.